# RavenDB taking forever to show updates

Tags: ravendb

I'm starting to assess our company using RavenDB for storing some stuff that doesn't really belong in a relational database (we're traditionally a SQL Server shop). I installed RavenDB locally on my machine, created a database, added a document. Nice!

Being a DBA, I decided to see how backups/restores work. I backed up my database, deleted it, then restored it from the backup. After refreshing my admin screen, I saw my database. I clicked on it, and got a message that the database doesn't exist.

After a couple hours, I tried again. Still doesn't exist. A full day later, I walk into work, and try again. This time the database works. I've had similar situations with updating documents. The update seems to take anywhere between 1 second - several hours to show an update...

Is this normal for RavenDB?? Am I completely misconfigured?? I run SQL Server on my local machine and it's lightning-fast, so I can't imagine updating a single document could take that long. As-is, I can't imagine recommending we use RavenDB for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying using indexes or getting documents by ID? Documents should be updated immediately (ACID). If indexes are slow to update (check their status using RavenDB Studio), it could be a configuration problem or something external like an anti-virus software can cause them to update slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, at least for the document-update latency, the default for caching in queries is enabled, so I was getting cached results.

Comment: Also discovered that using Firefox and/or Chrome instead of IE solved this completely

Answer (score 0):

Jeffery,
No, that isn't normal by a long short. You should be able to immediately see what was changed.
Note that certain AV products will interfere with the HTTP pipeline and can affect RavenDB's usage. The studio will also auto update things only every 5 seconds (to reduce UI jitter), but that is about it.

Restoring a database (from the same machine), should take only as long as it take to copy the files (pure I/O bound operation).
If this is from another machine using a different version of Windows, we might need to run a check on the file, which can take a bit of time, but that doesn't sound like your scenario